# Connect two monitors to one computer

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi, hp-pavilion

My HP has two DVI ports and one VGA port. I got two monitors which only accept VGA.

If I test them individually using the  DVI → VGA convertor and a DVI output then both the Acer and the Vizio monitor work.

If I try connecting both by connecting my Vizio to the DVI converted VGA and the Acer directly to the VGA output then the computer always **only** detects the monitor connected to the DVI connector.

Specifics:

- [HP Pavilion Elite HPE-350t CTO Desktop PC](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&product=4242295)
- Windows 8 Pro
- Core i7 CPU 860
- [ATI Radeon HD 5450 graphics card](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/hd-5450-overview/Pages/hd-5450-overview.aspx")
- [Vizio E221VA monitor](http://store.vizio.com/e221va.html)
- [Acer X191W Monitor](http://panam.acer.com/acerpanam/monitor/0000/Acer/X191/X191sp3.shtml)
- two VGA cords
- [One Digital to VGA converter](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Belkin-Pro-Series-DVI-I-TO-VGA-Digital-Video-Interface-Adapter-DVI-I-M-HDDB15F/3756909")

Comment: It should be a matter of simply hooking up both monitors to the desktop. What graphics card do you have, that system, has 10+ different graphic card options I am not going to look up every single one to determine whch does not support dual-monitors.  If the digital to vga cable worked just use that.  Your question leaves a great number of questions.

Comment: So sorry for not putting that on the specifics!: Radeon HD 5450

Comment: Update your question....Be sure the current version of `ATI Eyefinity` is installed. A VGA to HDMI cable will work in a case like this. **Your current adapter won't cut it.**  If using the adapter on the DVI-D port and the VGA port on the other monitor doesn't work, it means, you need additional hardware.

Comment: Do I need another DVI-D converter to VGA?

Answer (score -1):

Agree update your drivers for the card. Uninstall the drivers and then re-install.  That way any funky setting you may have chosen are reset.  Type of monitor shouldn't matter. Also see if your monitor works when connected to the VGA port by itself.  I have done what you are doing in the past just because of cables available and it has worked.  Did you add the card after market?  If so make sure your power source is sufficient, PC makers ship with the lower wattage power supply.  On my old HP when I changed cards I had to change power supplies too.  You need >400w.